# Best practice for front end library management using Bower

Tags: bower, bower-install

I want to use bower add manage my library, my question is along with the js files, it always comes with some extra json or git related files. I don't want to push those files to the client, is there a recommended way rather than extract js filed manually?

Comment: Make a branch of the repo with only the files needed called `dist` or something along those line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bower allows you define in your `bower.json` file a list of files it will ignore when installing your package:

> ignore
>
> Recommended Type: Array of String
>
> A list of files for Bower to ignore when installing your package.
>
> Note: README (all variants of case, .md, .text) and bower.json will
>   never be ignored.
>
> The ignore rules follow the same rules specified in the [gitignore pattern spec](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

For example:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "path/to/main.css",
  "ignore": [
    ".jshintrc",
    "**/*.txt"
  ],
  ...
}
```

Another option is keeping only the files you want to distribute in the Git tags which represents you package versions.